# How to configure a calendar to accept only a limited number of items

Tags: 2007, calendar

Can anyone advise if it's possible to configure a SharePoint 2007 list so that only accepts a specific number of entries on a specific date?

I have a calendar that has been set-up as a seminar self booking facility. Each seminar has a specific number of seats.  I'd like to know if it's possible to hide or bar submissions for entries on a specific day once the seating limit has been reached.

I don't have access to Visual Studio but I can use SPD, JQuery and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the NewItem form and with jQuery and/or SPServices, query the list on date selection, and set validation against posting the new item. Just have an event fire whenever the date changes to query the calendar, then if it pulls back a bool of items.count > value, set validation, and display validation text, and disable the Save button.

Here's the SPServices library and function that I would start with, GetListItems:http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems